# Assembly version of C code to launch a shell

Tags: assembly, buffer-overflow, shellcode, stack-smash

In buffer overflow assignment, I got a C file (`call_shellcode.c`) which contains an assembly version of the following C code which executes to open a shell:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    char *name[2];
    name[0] = "/bin/sh";
    name[1] = NULL;
    execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}
```

The code in file `call_shellcode.c` is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char code[] =
  "\x31\xc0"             /* xorl    %eax,%eax              */
  "\x50"                 /* pushl   %eax                   */
  "\x68""//sh"           /* pushl   $0x68732f2f            */
  "\x68""/bin"           /* pushl   $0x6e69622f            */
  "\x89\xe3"             /* movl    %esp,%ebx              */
  "\x50"                 /* pushl   %eax                   */
  "\x53"                 /* pushl   %ebx                   */
  "\x89\xe1"             /* movl    %esp,%ecx              */
  "\x99"                 /* cdql                           */
  "\xb0\x0b"             /* movb    $0x0b,%al              */
  "\xcd\x80"             /* int     $0x80                  */
;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char buf[sizeof(code)];
   strcpy(buf, code);
   ((void(*)( ))buf)( );
}
```

I've compiled it by command :

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o call_shellcode call_shellcode.c
```

When I execute it, it shows segmentation fault. Where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's 32-bit x86 machine code that uses the 32-bit `int 0x80 ABI`.

Assuming you're on a normal x86-64 Linux distro, you compiled it into a 64-bit executable, so those `push imm32` instructions decode as pushq, and also RSP is outside the low 32 bits of virtual address space. So `int 0x80` will return with `eax=-EFAULT` and execution continues into garbage, leading to a segfault.

Use `strace` or GDB to see this (although `strace` decodes `int 0x80` incorrectly in 64-bit executables, it will show the return value properly).  See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)

**Use `gcc -m32 -z execstack ..`** to make a 32-bit executable where this machine code will work.

Answer (score -1):

Use the command below

gcc -z execstack -g -o call_shellcode call_shellcode.c

Comment: The question is already using `-z execstack` - the key thing they're missing is `-m32`, as the existing answer points out.